# javascript += operator

Tags: javascript, c#, dom-events

In my JSON javascript live pull I have:

```
    html += "<tr><td width=60 valign=top><a href='"+item.url+"' target='_blank'>"+item.site+"</a></td>";
```

The += seems to strip out my tr td values
So I tried amending it to = which just seems to fail.. I tried setting td as a var and still no luck

Any ideas of a way round this, my js is basic so even if you think its silly your answer could help me greatly..

EDIT

to confuse things things further the = alone works in Firefox but on IE the items are loading hidden in the background.. I don't get why the browsers would perform so differently over the use of one + sign...

Comment: You don't seem to be closing the `<a>`

Comment: How are you trying to use this `html` value?  How do you know those things are being stripped?

Comment: You should show us some more of your code. What is the value of `html` before the line you include? What are you doing with it after setting/appending to it?

Comment: EDIT They are displayed table less in the browser.. and viewing the output both tag are missing

Comment: When you say "output" do you mean the **html source**?  Or do you mean the rendered content in the browser?

Comment: The rendered output using firefox view selection source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x += y` is just a shorthand for `x = x + y`. If you change it to `html = "..."`, you'd be overwriting anything that already existed in the `html` variable.

How are your "tr td values" being stripped?

Comment: Clobbered... is that a technical term? ;)

Comment: Heh, I didn't mean to use it twice in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
html += "<tr><td width=60 valign=top><a href='"+item.url+"' target='_blank'>"+item.site+"</a></td></tr>";
```

Your markup generated is invalid (not closing the anchor tag) so it's possible the browser isn't interpreting the html very well.

Comment: that was just a mistake when rewriting it here haha

Comment: You should update your question then as it's misleading. I hope you didn't downvote because of that fact as someone did. You should also consider posting more code than one line as the line in question may not even be the issue at all.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, I appreciate the help.. I'm bad at coding but now quite that bad hahah